# Irrationality proof by fast converging series?

Tags: irrational-numbers

I read here https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath455/kmath455.htm that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{d_n}$ is irrational if $d_{n+1} > d_{n}^2$ for all $n > N_0$.

> **Can we prove $\pi$, $e$ or some other numbers irrational by creating a series for them that converges like this?**

I looked on wikipedia if there were some already and found Ramanujans series for $\pi$: $$\frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9801} \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(4k)!(1103+26390k)}{(k!)^4 396^{4k}}$$ and (if I did the inequality correct) even this is not fast enough for irrationality of $\pi$!

Comment: If applicable at all, the Ramanujan series would show that $\pi\sqrt 2$ is irrational, thus still leaving the possibility  that $\pi$ itself is rational.

Comment: Just be careful, because the $d_i$ in the above theorem need to be integers

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, good point! Thank you for mentioning that.

Comment: It's not hard to prove the irrationality of $e$ by looking at the rate of convergence of $\sum 1/n!$. This is done in Rudin's Principles, for example. The quadratic estimate you quoted is asking more than is necessary.

Comment: @5PM, yeah that proof is very nice. I am interested in whether this particular irrationality criterion has value, and as you mention it is not strong enough to apply to the sequence n!. I think the answer to my question is that it doesn't really have a use, non-contrived numbers don't seem to have such fast converging series.